# Python Flask, downloading a file from server

Tags: python, html, flask

I have created a web application, which allows its users to download files from the same server the application is running on. However, I can't make it work the way I want it to work, and now I'm not even sure if it's possible.

So, I have a form, which contains two user inputs and a "Download" button. The first user input lets you choose a file and the second user input lets you choose amount. When you hit the the download button, the application creates a zip file based on user input, and tries to send it to user. Anyway, the zip file is never sent to user.

Here's what the button looks like in html

`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download" class="btn" >`

And below is the `send_file()` function call in the application.

```
send_file(uploads + cfg_zipfile, attachment_filename=cfg_zipfile, as_attachment=True)
```

The function returns status 200, so it seems to be working. Still, no file is sent, but the file exists on the server. So, is this even possible to do it this way? I know I could create the zip file with the button, then a download link would appear and a user could download it from the link, but is it possible to get all this functionality with one button? Currently zip file's name also depends on user input (file chosen and amount).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a service

```
 <button ng-show='downloadReportview' data-toggle="modal"  class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-download">
    <a href="http://{{location}}/api/xx/xxxx//{{costDataReportName}}"  download>Download Report</a>
  </button>
```

This will call the service using GET method. 
And the service in python will look smth like this :

```
def get(self, filename):
    # RETURN THE INVOICE
    file_name = str(expanduser("~")) + UPLOAD_PATH + str(filename)
    f = open(file_name, "rb")
    output = f.read()
    self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=output.csv')
    self.set_header('Content-type', 'text/csv')
    self.write(output)
    print("Invoice download")
```